# Small sliding, loop gallery

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a website and I'd like to add a photo gallery. The gallery should work as follows:

The gallery has a rectangle/box form. I have, let's say, 10 photos. 7 of them are displayed in a gallery, the rest is hidden. By clicking buttons "left" or "right" we can move photos in the given direction and so view a photo that was hidden (and hid a photo that was on the far left or right side). The gallery should be loop, so a button won't stop moving photos when it reaches the last photo, but start viewing photos from the beginning (starting with the very first one) instead. I know HTML and CSS, but, if I'm right, CSS itself is not enough to make such gallery. I think I need some Javascript code for this, but I don't know JS. I've searched on the net for JS gallery scripts, but none of them works and looks as I'd like them to work and look.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of galleries that fit your criteria. You'll have to do a little tinkering to get it to work exactly how you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/). I think it offers exactly what you need.